# How to create new string by replacing with string from another file in awk/linux

Tags: linux, awk

I have two files as shown below:

```
FileA:
AGCTTTTCATTC...

FileB:
POS ID  REF ALT
 2   .   G   C
 8   .   C   -
 12  .   -   T
```

POS column in FileB: gives the string position in FileA: i.e 2 under POS means second letter "G" in the sequence in FileA.

Based on the POS column in FileB, FileA should be modified to FileA'and FileB'as shown below.

FileA' is formed by inserting string under REF column at respective positions in POS column

FileB' is formed by replacing string under ALT column at respective positions in POS column. And

```
FileA':
AGCTTTTCATT-TC...

FileB':    
ACCTTTT-ATTTTC...
```

Answer (score 0):

Perl solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

open my $DNA, '<', 'FileA' or die $!;
open my $POS, '<', 'FileB' or die $!;

my $dna = <$DNA>;
my $ref_out = $dna;
my $alt_out = $dna;
while (<$POS>) {
    my ($pos, $id, $ref, $alt) = split;
    next unless $pos =~ /^\d+$/; # Skip the header.
    substr $ref_out, $pos - 1, 1, $ref;
    substr $alt_out, $pos - 1, 1, $alt;
}
open my $REF, '>', "FileA'" or die $!;
print {$REF} $ref_out;
close $REF;

open my $ALT, '>', "FileB'" or die $!;
print {$ALT} $alt_out;
close $ALT;
```

You just keep two copies of the input string and modify it via [substr](http://p3rl.org/substr) for each line of FileB.

Comment: Hi, i tried your solution. The output remains unchanged when executed as script.pl. Could you help further to run through the script. thanks in advance.

Comment: @chas: It should create two new files, `FileA'` and `FileB'`.